# What is the shortcut to find an artifact in the maven dependency diagram in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IDEA, one can ask for the dependency diagram of a project via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. This diagram is mostly to large and crowded, so searching is a very useful action to use. When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> a popup named "Diagram elements" is shown. This works with the default key mapping. In my case, I use the eclipse shortcuts (these are compatible with my brain) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> does not work. Also I cannot find the action in the settings > keymap dialog to see what the shortcut for me is (or change it).

Does anyone happen to know what the shortcut in the eclipse keymap is ? Or what the name of the action is ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the action responsible for this. It is `Main Menu > Edit > Find > Find...`
It is defined in the `Default` keymap, but not in the `Eclipse` one.
By the way, this also makes the searching in the console possible. That does not work either in the `Eclipse` keymap.